# Removing Chromium B.S.U

Tags: apt, chromium

I was trying to download chromium by using  `sudo apt-get install chromium`, and I ended up getting chromium B.S.U. It won't open and I want to get rid of it, but I can' even find where it is. How do I delete it.

Answer (score 3):

This is a more complete solution:

```
sudo apt-get purge chromium
```

and

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

The difference between the two (remove and purge) is that remove leaves behind the configuration files. Running autoremove will also remove any dependencies that are no longer needed.

Answer (score 1):

Use the command:

```
sudo apt-get remove chromium
```